# Is it possible to use a String as a seed for an instance Random?

Tags: java, android

I have a String value and I would like to init a random class using the string as a seed?

Is it possible to do this, and if so how?

The string consists not only of ASCII. I can have any utf-8 symbols.

Comment: Simply said, you can't. Random is a number. You'll have to convert the string to a number (**long**), first to use that number as a seed for Random - if the string contains a number or if it is convertable... For your reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html

Comment: You could run a CRC32 on it and the resulting integer would be your seed.http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/CRC32.html

Comment: Or you could convert from base 36, if your string contains only a-z and 0*9 characters (i.e.: strip out all the punctuation chars and all the spaces from a sentence in English)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel but if I have string not in english? If have 10 chars utf-8 string. It is 20 bytes, or 160 bits. It's 2^160 variants. Not too much for long?

Comment: The CRC32 returns a long anyway (it's only an error correction code): http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/CRC32.html

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel This question is NOT a duplicate of "How to convert String to long in Java?" That question specifically states the string is numbers. This question implies the string is consisting of more than numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the implementation of `String.hashCode`, with the difference of using `long` instead of `int`

```
static long stringToSeed(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    long hash = 0;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        hash = 31L*hash + c;
    }
    return hash;
}
```

This way you get a `long`, but of course there are different `String`s that can produce the same seed. Depending on the `String`s you use as input, some seeds may occur with a higher probability than others.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something with the ascii values, or utf-8 symbols, write them all as number, add them together. Or, if you need to, you can choose a more advanced 'hashing function' for examples see the following wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions